# Getting next twelve months from the current year

Tags: iphone, ios

Trying to get next twelve months of current year from current month. Below is my code i am trying, but it was picking from the next month, so i modified it but now it shows the current month for 2014 and others from 2013.

```
 NSDateFormatter  *dateFormatter   = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate           *today           = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar       *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *monthComponents = [currentCalendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
int currentMonth = [monthComponents month];

NSDateComponents *yearComponents  = [currentCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit  fromDate:today];
int currentYear  = [yearComponents year];
int nextYear     = currentYear + 1;

int months  = 1;
int year;
for(int m = currentMonth-1; months < 12; m++){

int nextMonth = m % 12;

if(nextMonth < currentMonth){
    year = nextYear;
} else {
    year = currentYear;
}

NSLog(@"%@ %i",[[dateFormatter monthSymbols] objectAtIndex: nextMonth],year);

months++;
}
```

This is the output from the link below.

```
August 2013
September 2013
October 2013
November 2013
December 2013
January 2014
February 2014
March 2014
April 2014
```

2013-07-09 12:54:48.683 MyEventApp[13562:c07] May 2014
2013-07-09 12:54:48.683 MyEventApp[13562:c07] June 2014
2013-07-09 12:54:48.683 MyEventApp[13562:c07] July 2014

Took help from this link [Get Month and year of 1 year advance in iPhone.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462946/get-month-and-year-of-1-year-advance-in-iphone)

This is from my modified code.

```
July 2014
August 2013
September 2013
October 2013
November 2013
December 2013
January 2014
February 2014
March 2014
April 2014
May 2014
June 2014
```

Comment: So you need to ask how to do `+1`?

Comment: Take current date, create `nsdatecomponents` with `month` set to `1`, add 12 times. Use `NSDateFormatter` to format the dates.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change this line

```
if(nextMonth < currentMonth)
```

to

```
if(nextMonth < currentMonth-1)
```